# How to get the ttk Button background color?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I want to programmatically find out what color is being used for the background color of a tkinter `ttk.Button`. To be clear, I'm not trying to set or change the background color (since that cannot be done), merely get the color so I can use that color elsewhere. The standard process of `cget('background')` will not work for a ttk button, so how else might I get the button background color?

Note, this answer needs to be system independent.

Comment: Why would you want to find out the button background color if it didn't change from the default  one ?

Comment: @TrakJohnson As I said in my question, I want to use that color to elsewhere. Specifically I want to change the color of other components to that color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself eventually.

```
from tkinter import ttk
print(ttk.Style().lookup('TButton', 'background'))
```